# Need help to integrate a discretized data

Tags: numerical-integration

Below I have a data organized as: `data= {{x1,y1,f[x1,y1]},{x2,y2,f[x2,y2]},...{xn,yn,f[xn,yn}}`

I need a function interpolation and the integral of this function over the domain `{x,0,1},{y,0,1}`.  Can anyone help please?

```
list={{0., 0., 0.590293}, {0.25, 0., 0.669859}, {0.5, 0., 0.699156}, {0.75,
   0., 0.669859}, {0., 0.25, 0.669859}, {0.25, 0.25, 0.774109}, {0.5, 
  0.25, 0.812169}, {0.75, 0.25, 0.774109}, {0., 0.5, 0.699156}, {0.25,
   0.5, 0.812169}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.853614}, {0.75, 0.5, 0.812169}, {0., 
  0.75, 0.669859}, {0.25, 0.75, 0.774109}, {0.5, 0.75, 
  0.812169}, {0.75, 0.75, 0.774109}, {0., 0.125, 0.630076}, {0.25, 
  0.125, 0.721984}, {0.5, 0.125, 0.755662}, {0.75, 0.125, 
  0.721984}, {0., 0.375, 0.684507}, {0.25, 0.375, 0.793139}, {0.5, 
  0.375, 0.832891}, {0.75, 0.375, 0.793139}, {0., 0.625, 
  0.684507}, {0.25, 0.625, 0.793139}, {0.5, 0.625, 0.832891}, {0.75, 
  0.625, 0.793139}, {0., 0.875, 0.630076}, {0.25, 0.875, 
  0.721984}, {0.5, 0.875, 0.755662}, {0.75, 0.875, 0.721984}, {0., 
  0.25, 0.669859}, {0.25, 0.25, 0.774109}, {0.5, 0.25, 
  0.812169}, {0.75, 0.25, 0.774109}, {0., 0.5, 0.699156}, {0.25, 0.5, 
  0.812169}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.853614}, {0.75, 0.5, 0.812169}, {0., 0.75, 
  0.669859}, {0.25, 0.75, 0.774109}, {0.5, 0.75, 0.812169}, {0.75, 
  0.75, 0.774109}, {0., 1., 0.590293}, {0.25, 1., 0.669859}, {0.5, 1.,
   0.699156}, {0.75, 1., 0.669859}, {0.125, 0., 0.630076}, {0.375, 0.,
   0.684507}, {0.625, 0., 0.684507}, {0.875, 0., 0.630076}, {0.125, 
  0.25, 0.721984}, {0.375, 0.25, 0.793139}, {0.625, 0.25, 
  0.793139}, {0.875, 0.25, 0.721984}, {0.125, 0.5, 0.755662}, {0.375, 
  0.5, 0.832891}, {0.625, 0.5, 0.832891}, {0.875, 0.5, 
  0.755662}, {0.125, 0.75, 0.721984}, {0.375, 0.75, 0.793139}, {0.625,
   0.75, 0.793139}, {0.875, 0.75, 0.721984}, {0.125, 0.125, 
  0.67603}, {0.375, 0.125, 0.738823}, {0.625, 0.125, 
  0.738823}, {0.875, 0.125, 0.67603}, {0.125, 0.375, 
  0.738823}, {0.375, 0.375, 0.813015}, {0.625, 0.375, 
  0.813015}, {0.875, 0.375, 0.738823}, {0.125, 0.625, 
  0.738823}, {0.375, 0.625, 0.813015}, {0.625, 0.625, 
  0.813015}, {0.875, 0.625, 0.738823}, {0.125, 0.875, 
  0.67603}, {0.375, 0.875, 0.738823}, {0.625, 0.875, 
  0.738823}, {0.875, 0.875, 0.67603}, {0.125, 0.25, 0.721984}, {0.375,
   0.25, 0.793139}, {0.625, 0.25, 0.793139}, {0.875, 0.25, 
  0.721984}, {0.125, 0.5, 0.755662}, {0.375, 0.5, 0.832891}, {0.625, 
  0.5, 0.832891}, {0.875, 0.5, 0.755662}, {0.125, 0.75, 
  0.721984}, {0.375, 0.75, 0.793139}, {0.625, 0.75, 0.793139}, {0.875,
   0.75, 0.721984}, {0.125, 1., 0.630076}, {0.375, 1., 
  0.684507}, {0.625, 1., 0.684507}, {0.875, 1., 0.630076}, {0.25, 0., 
  0.669859}, {0.5, 0., 0.699156}, {0.75, 0., 0.669859}, {1., 0., 
  0.590293}, {0.25, 0.25, 0.774109}, {0.5, 0.25, 0.812169}, {0.75, 
  0.25, 0.774109}, {1., 0.25, 0.669859}, {0.25, 0.5, 0.812169}, {0.5, 
  0.5, 0.853614}, {0.75, 0.5, 0.812169}, {1., 0.5, 0.699156}, {0.25, 
  0.75, 0.774109}, {0.5, 0.75, 0.812169}, {0.75, 0.75, 0.774109}, {1.,
   0.75, 0.669859}, {0.25, 0.125, 0.721984}, {0.5, 0.125, 
  0.755662}, {0.75, 0.125, 0.721984}, {1., 0.125, 0.630076}, {0.25, 
  0.375, 0.793139}, {0.5, 0.375, 0.832891}, {0.75, 0.375, 
  0.793139}, {1., 0.375, 0.684507}, {0.25, 0.625, 0.793139}, {0.5, 
  0.625, 0.832891}, {0.75, 0.625, 0.793139}, {1., 0.625, 
  0.684507}, {0.25, 0.875, 0.721984}, {0.5, 0.875, 0.755662}, {0.75, 
  0.875, 0.721984}, {1., 0.875, 0.630076}, {0.25, 0.25, 
  0.774109}, {0.5, 0.25, 0.812169}, {0.75, 0.25, 0.774109}, {1., 0.25,
   0.669859}, {0.25, 0.5, 0.812169}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.853614}, {0.75, 0.5,
   0.812169}, {1., 0.5, 0.699156}, {0.25, 0.75, 0.774109}, {0.5, 0.75,
   0.812169}, {0.75, 0.75, 0.774109}, {1., 0.75, 0.669859}, {0.25, 1.,
   0.669859}, {0.5, 1., 0.699156}, {0.75, 1., 0.669859}, {1., 1., 
  0.590293}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this way:

```
data = Table[{{list[[i]][[1]], list[[i]][[2]]}, list[[i]][[3]]}, {i, 
     1, Length[list]}] // N;
data = DeleteDuplicates[data];
f = Interpolation[data];
NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]

0.743101
```

Comment: You can shorten the first line to `data = {Most@#, Last@#} & /@ list;`

Comment: Looks like you don't need the first line. You can start from `data = DeleteDuplicates[list];`. And you can accept your answer if it solves your problem :).